# CSS elements not wrapped properly

Tags: css

I've got these 2 CSS classes and they do not appear inside their container:

```
.container{
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.container::after{
  content:"";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}    
.gauche{
       float: left;
       background-color: yellow;
       height: 25px;
       width: 50%;
 }
 .droite{
       float:left;
       width: 50%;
       height: 25px;
       background-color: blue;
 }

<div class = 'container'>
  <div class = 'gauche'></div>
  <div class = 'droite'></div>
</div>
```

If they appear, the red border must wrap them, which thing isn't the case. Any suggestion on how to fix this?

[**jsBin**](http://jsbin.com/doduqetuke/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Thank you for the roll-back @MichaelSchmidt

Comment: No Problem. I edited the question to make a snippet of your question. So the questions shouldn't already contain the answer below. So I removed the `overflow: hidden` in the snippet. Is this your snippet BEFORE the answer?

Comment: @MichaelSchmidt Yes, this snippet is mine BEFORE the answer was posted (the answerer added one property only, so that is why my question and his answer look similar, but not the same). After I accepted the edit of the first user, I guessed my question was unclear but did not know how to revert my post back, so thank you again.

Comment: @J.Doe In your code about, you left a `.` in front of the `container`.

Comment: You are absolutely right ... in my jsBin I had a `.` in front of `container::after { ... }` so I will add it right now (and you too :D ) @PraveenKumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear the floats by using `overflow: hidden` for the parent.

```css
.container{
  overflow: hidden;       /* Add this here. */
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
container::after{
  content:"";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
.gauche{
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 25px;
  width: 50%;
}
.droite{
  float:left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'container'>
  <div class = 'gauche'></div>
  <div class = 'droite'></div>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]